# How to run build version using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, build, production, create-react-app

So, I developed a small React application using create-react-app. (I have always made applications from scratch.)

Then, after I was kind of happy with it, I decided to run `npm run build` to make an optimized production build.

Can someone please tell me how I can run the production build instead of the Dev build?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

When you run `npm run build` your console should actually say something like the following

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

The build script is building your entire app into the build folder, ready to be statically served. However actually serving it require some kind of static file server, like the the one they propose.

After running the command `serve -s build` you can access your production build at localhost (on the specified port).

You can of course run whatever static file server you like, I usually use express for this, however `serve` seems like the easiest option to just serve your statics files with a single command.

Comment: I have done this, i want this `serve -s build` to run in background with forever, but it gives error

Comment: forever is command that let us some process in background. Please refer this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: What command are you running with forever, and what error du you get? Maybe this should be asked as another stackoverflow question, since it is not directly related to the given question

Comment: @the_cheff I have done the above steps, and got the urls for the running server. But i am not access those urls. getting site cant be reached.

Comment: @Sravani did your build succeed, check that you actually have something in your build folder.

Comment: Even I followed these steps but the files didn't runs. It gives error: `serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had to make sure the `homepage` field in my `package.json` is set to `.` to serve the files from any directory.

Comment: try ```npx serve -s build```

Comment: @the_cheff Where does it install packages after this command `npm install -g serve`?

Comment: @Perkone it is installed globally (that is why we use -g). You can see where the global packages are installed with the command `npm list -g --depth=0`

Comment: globally installing and running serve -s build works..

Comment: Is there any difference if `homepage` of `package.json`  or `PUBLIC_URL` is set?

Comment: This gives following error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: `serve` does not support non-root mode: https://github.com/vercel/serve/issues/556

Comment: @ReemaParakh to run the process in background, you may use PM2 https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Answer (score 44):

Also you can use "serve" tool, using "npx". in this case no need to install it globally.

```
npx serve -s build
```

Comment: 404 | the requested path could not be found

Comment: Might be helpful for others: the `serve` should be from outside the `build` folder

Comment: This is the proper answer, no need to install that package, just run it once

Comment: "404 | the requested path could not be found" -> You need to run "npm run build" before ;)

Answer (score 16):

Navigate inside the directory of your app first.

According to the official create-react-app website. When you run `npm run build` you create a `build` directory with a production build of your app.

After running the command above the next thing you can do to check the build version of your app is to to install `serve` to serve your status site on the port **5000** by default.

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

This will copy the link to your clipboard that you can paste in your browser and see the build version of you app.

Comment: you can also do this in a single line: `npx serve -s build`

Answer (score 6):

First of all run

```
npm install -g serve
```

It will install globally the serve, and then execute

```
serve -s build
```

Answer (score 4):

use this command :  npm install -g serve -s build

Comment: Can you give a short explanation what the command does and what the flags mean?

Comment: You need to install serve globally if you want to practice running the production build. This command makes sense to me - I think it answers the question in a narrow way.

Answer (score 2):

You've to first install serve package globally.

If you're using yarn, run this command to do so: `yarn global add serve`.

For npm: `npm install -g serve`

And then execute:
`serve -s build`