# Routing error in index.html of react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

i have a project with this structure
main folder : BridgeItFronEnd ( i know, it's spelled uncorrectly) and under this folder i have several folders among which "app" where all my code is under.

My webpack.prod.babel is this :

```
    // Important modules this config uses
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackPwaManifest = require('webpack-pwa-manifest');
const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');
const { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  mode: 'production',

  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js')],

  // Utilize long-term caching by adding content hashes (not compilation hashes) to compiled assets
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    sideEffects: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    splitChunks: { chunks: 'all' },
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },

  plugins: [
    // Minify and optimize the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),

    // Put it in the end to capture all the HtmlWebpackPlugin's
    // assets manipulations and do leak its manipulations to HtmlWebpackPlugin
    new OfflinePlugin({
      relativePaths: true,
      publicPath: '/',
      appShell: '/',

      // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
      // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],

      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],

        // All chunks marked as `additional`, loaded after main section
        // and do not prevent SW to install. Change to `optional` if
        // do not want them to be preloaded at all (cached only when first loaded)
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },

      // Removes warning for about `additional` section usage
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,
    }),

    new WebpackPwaManifest({
      name: 'React Boilerplate',
      short_name: 'React BP',
      description: 'My React Boilerplate-based project!',
      background_color: '#fafafa',
      theme_color: '#b1624d',
      icons: [
        {
          src: path.resolve('app/images/icon-512x512.png'),
          sizes: [72, 96, 120, 128, 144, 152, 167, 180, 192, 384, 512],
        },
      ],
    }),

    new HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      hashFunction: 'sha256',
      hashDigest: 'hex',
      hashDigestLength: 20,
    }),
  ],

  performance: {
    assetFilter: assetFilename =>
      !/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename),
      },
    });
```

my webpack.prod.base is

```
   /**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Remove this line once the following warning goes away (it was meant for webpack loader authors not users):
// 'DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic,
// see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56 parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions()
// in the next major version of loader-utils.'
process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports = options => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign(
    {
      // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      publicPath: (process.env.NODE_ENV==='development'?'/':'./'),
    },
    options.output,
  ), // Merge with env dependent settings
  optimization: options.optimization,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false,
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // make fetch available
      fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),

    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; UglifyJS will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

when i generate the build i have a bunch of chunks in a build folder and an index.html. If i run that everything works fine since i added the relative path ./ in the webpack configuration but routing does not work I end up getting the page not found component .
Here is my app.js

```
/**
 * app.js
 *
 * This is the entry file for the application, only setup and boilerplate
 * code.
 */

// Needed for redux-saga es6 generator support
import 'babel-polyfill';

// Import all the third party stuff
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import localforage from 'localforage'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/BridgeItFronEnd/', });

// Import root app
import App from 'containers/App/index';

// Import Language Provider
import LanguageProvider from 'containers/LanguageProvider';

// Load the favicon and the .htaccess file
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./images/favicon.ico';
import 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./.htaccess'; // eslint-disable-line import/extensions

import configureStore from './globalStore/configureStore';

// Import i18n messages
import { translationMessages } from './i18n';

// Import CSS reset and Global Styles
import './global-styles';

import { isOnline } from './containers/App/store/actions'
// Observe loading of Open Sans (to remove open sans, remove the <link> tag in
// the index.html file and this observer)
const openSansObserver = new FontFaceObserver('Open Sans', {});

// When Open Sans is loaded, add a font-family using Open Sans to the body
openSansObserver.load().then(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('fontLoaded');
});

// Create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
//const history = createHistory();
const { store, persistor } = configureStore(initialState, history);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

  window.addEventListener("online",() => store.dispatch(isOnline(true)))
  window.addEventListener("offline", () => store.dispatch(isOnline(false)))


// temporary create localforage db and threee differents tables

localforage.config({
  driver      : localforage.INDEXEDDB, // Force WebSQL; same as using setDriver()
  name        : 'BridgeIt',
  version     : 1.0,
  storeName   : 'media', // Should be alphanumeric, with underscores.
  description : 'some description'
});


const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </LanguageProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  // Hot reloadable React components and translation json files
  // modules.hot.accept does not accept dynamic dependencies,
  // have to be constants at compile-time
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render(translationMessages);
  });
}

// Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support
if (!window.Intl) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(import('intl'));
  })
    .then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js'),
        import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/de.js'),
      ]),
    )
    .then(() => render(translationMessages))
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
} else {
  render(translationMessages);
}

// Install ServiceWorker and AppCache in the end since
// it's not most important operation and if main code fails,
// we do not want it installed
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install(); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

and here's my routing :

```
/**
 *
 * App
 *
 * This component is the skeleton around the actual pages, and should only
 * contain code that should be seen on all pages. (e.g. navigation bar)
 */

import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from '../HomePage/Loadable';
import FeaturePage from 'containers/FeaturePage/Loadable';
import NotFoundPage from '..//NotFoundPage/Loadable';
import TestContainer from '../TestContainer/index';
import { Login } from '../Login/login';
import Procedure from '../Procedure/Procedure';
import ImageShower from '../Identification/imageShower';
import IdentificationWithLocalStorage from '../Identification/index';

const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/features" component={FeaturePage} />
        <Route path="/testContainer" component={TestContainer} />
        <Route path="/Procedure" component={Procedure} />
        <Route path="/Identification" component={IdentificationWithLocalStorage} />
        <Route path="/ImageShower" component={ImageShower} />
        <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}
```

So when i load index.html ( generated from the build) into the browser i get this link

```
http://localhost:63342/BridgeItFronEnd/build/index.html?_ijt=q2vhihun8bn8su5bg8q68353h5
```

and no matter what i put after / in the url i end up in the Page not found route. How can i fix this? And most of all WHY? So i can understand better and avoid making the same mistake again.
Thank you so much in advance for the time and patience!

Comment: How are you trying to run the build version ??

Comment: Yes, i run "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout" 

 then i open the generated index.html file

Comment: hmm. I wonder how it is related. This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208528/how-to-run-build-version-using-create-react-app