# The bundle does not load. blank screen after building react project

Tags: reactjs

as I understand, after building the project, the bundle does not load, or I write something wrong in the router-dom, or I need to add something to json.. an empty screen..

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './app/home/Home';
import AboutTheProject from './app/home/pages/page_1/AboutTheProject'; 
import HowItWorks from './app/home/pages/page_3/HowItWorks'; 
import Detailed from './app/home/pages/page_3/moreDetailed/Detailed'; 
import RedactorMenu from './app/workspace/RedactorMenu';
import Title from './app/workspace/Title';   

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/about" element={<AboutTheProject />} />
                    <Route path="/works" element={<HowItWorks />} /> 
                    <Route path="/works/detailed" element={<Detailed />} />
                    <Route path="/workspace" element={<RedactorMenu />} />
                    <Route path="/workspace/prototype" element={<Title />} />
                </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

.....

```
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from "./App";


const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to change the router but it doesn't help. blank screen

Comment: How do you serve the files?

Comment: @gorden Please don't use images where is no need. Write code instead of images.

Comment: in what sense do I serve files?

Comment: @gorden, as I'm seeing, look fine in my side. In any case, check your HTML file and div which have ID. maybe it's cause that problem.

Comment: He's all right. I don't understand what the problem is anymore

Comment: @gorden, when you add router package then you're facing that or it's just not show any things without ```router``` package

Comment: Why do you have "/build" in your URL? "/build" is not registered as a Route and you dont have a fallback routes (404 one).

Comment: but I don't run locally. when I just run npm start, everything is fine. And when I write npx serve, the screen is empty again

Comment: /build appears when I run using npx serve

Comment: I guess it should be `npx serve -s build`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208528/how-to-run-build-version-using-create-react-app

Comment: everything works without router-dom