# webpack configuration for production is serving only on dist folder and not inject js file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin =
  require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require("external-remotes-plugin");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require("@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });
module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
    mode: "production",
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
    },
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      clean: true,
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "swc-loader",
            options: {
              jsc: {
                parser: {
                  syntax: "typescript",
                  tsx: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "swc-loader",
            options: {
              jsc: {
                parser: {
                  syntax: "typescript",
                  tsx: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          //COMPONENTE
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          type: "asset",
          resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
        },
        {
          //URL
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          resourceQuery: { not: [/url/] }, // exclude react component if *.svg?url
          use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(scss|css)$/i,

          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader",
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
                },
                importLoaders: 1,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
          exclude: /\.(ttf|eot|woff(2)?)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "images/[name].[hash].[ext]",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff(2)?)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "./fonts/",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js"],
      alias: {
        "@api": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/api"),
        "@adapters": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/adapters"),
        "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
        "@context": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/context"),
        "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
        "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages"),
        "@hooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hooks"),
        "@shared": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/shared"),
        "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils"),
        "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles"),
        "@services": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/services"),
        "@routes": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/routes"),
      },
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        React: "react",
      }),

      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "main",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {
          acquisitions: "acquisitions@[acquisitionsUrl]/remoteEntry.js",
        },
        shared: {
          ...deps,
          react: {
            requiredVersion: require("react").version,
            import: "react", // the "react" package will be used a provided and fallback module
            shareKey: "react", // under this name the shared module will be placed in the share scope
            shareScope: "default", // share scope with this name will be used
            singleton: true, //
          },
          "styled-components": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps["styled-components"],
          },
          "@emotion/react": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps["@emotion/react"],
          },
          "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: require("react-dom").version,
          },

          "shared-contexts": {
            import: "shared-contexts",
            requiredVersion: require("../../packages/contexts/package.json")
              .version,
          },
        },
      }),
      new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /bootstrap\.js$/],
        esModule: true,
        overlay: { sockProtocol: "ws" },
      }),
      new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: "head",
        template: "./public/index.html",
        chunks: ["entry"],
      }),
      new LiveReloadPlugin({
        port: 35729,
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

then a use this file to make a production build, the I go to the dist folder and run

```
npx http-server .
```

and when I go to the http://localhost:8081 the browser show the following image

[image]

but instead it should be serving the website, then if I make a click on the dist folder, the browser serve the index.html file, but this file does not have the correspondig script tag with the main.js file. I try different config but can make work.

The  website should be server from the root (http://localhost:8081/) and the index.html must has injected the main.js files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are running npx serve from `dist` folder and not from the root of the project. I have same structure and `index.html` file is at root and working fine.

Try adding index.html file in root directory where the `webpack.config.js` is. and then run webpack `webpack serve --mode development` and it should serve the index.html from there.

Comment: Im trying to create the production build and testing on my local…my development env work great with webpack server

Comment: I am not getting it. Is it that your production build should work while running npx serve from dist? is there any change in production apart from minification and stripping out unnecessary code? May be still this question might be helpful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208528/how-to-run-build-version-using-create-react-app